Does Birkat kohanim have to be read with the trop
According to Halacha, is it required for a Kohen reciting Birkat kohanim to recite it in the trop/cantillation notes, or no? Are there different opinions on this by custom (Ashkenazi, Sephardi, Yemenite, Hasidic)?

In Ashkenazi communities (where they only duchen on yom tov) they sing the words to a yom tov tune. (Nowadays with the general decline in cantorial study, it's most common to just find approximate monotones.) Not sure why you are asking about trop. Have you ever seen that?

Birkat Kohanim is sung, not read, and there are various styles of chanting used by different Kohanim. It is particularly noticeable in Israel where it is said every day and will vary from one day to the next depending on the Kohen/Kohanim

Nothing of the sort is mentioned in halacha. No community I know of does so. The way it is described in Halacha and done in practice is a word by word call and response between the chazzan and kohanim.

FYI: In some shuls the Kohanim sing a special tune without words while the congregation says the spcial prayers associated with the last words of each section of the blessing. In a few yekkish shuls, there is a different tune for each Yom Tov.

@Avrohom not only in yekkish shuls

Singing the words is definitely a traditional practice brought in halacha https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37124/759 not just dry call and response

@DoubleAA It is a call-and-response with singing in the middle in Ashkenazic communities on holidays.

@N.T. Not just in the middle. Traditionally the words themselves are sung (cf https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20252/humming-as-an-interruption-during-birkat-kohanim/20392#comment435566_20392 ) (as above this is no longer so common)
